# Is there a logic-to-numeral mapping which preserves uniqueness (contrary to the Gödel coding)?

Tags: computability

Given the two equivalent terms $A \vee B$ and $B \vee A$, Gödel numbering returns two various codes $2^{4}.3^{\overline{A}+1}.5^{\overline{B}+1}$ and $2^{4}.3^{\overline{B}+1}.5^{\overline{A}+1}$, respectively. These two codes do not generally equal to each other, which is an unfortunate if one would like to observe the equivalence after the mapping. Thus, is there any alternative logic-to-numeral mapping which takes such symmetries into account, for example, by yielding one code corresponding to both $A \vee B$ and $B \vee A$?

Comment: $A\vee B$ and $B\vee A$ are two different words. The *equivalence* that you mention is   an interpretation that you are giving to the existence of another word, which constitutes a proof of that equivalence. To produce what you want you would need to be more precise on what words you want to consider 'equivalent'.

Comment: @plop: By `equivalent`, I indeed mean those words whose elements can be symmetrically replaced by each other. In a more rigorous term, those whose truth tables read each other.

Comment: @plop: By the way, would you please explain why the two assumed words are "different"?

Comment: That is still not clear. There are many things to be defined. Exactly which formal language are you trying encode? When are two words going to be considered equivalent? What constitutes a proof of that equivalence? Does an algorithm exist to decide when two words are equivalent? | If you only care about truth tables, then you only need to encode truth tables. This is a bunch of rows in binary. You could just put the corresponding integers as exponents of the primes $2,3,5,7,...$

Comment: The first character of $A\vee B$ is $A$, while the first character of $B\vee A$ is $B$. The reason why you are seeing them as equivalent is because probably in your language there is a third word, which you consider the proof of that equivalence. For example, the word $A\vee B \equiv B\vee A$, or $A\vee B\iff B\vee A$. I don't know. It depends on your language.

Comment: Since the truth table for $A\vee B$ and for $B\vee A$ (ordering the inputs in ascending order) is $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&1\\\end{pmatrix}$, its rows are the numbers $0,3,5,7$. Then we encode it as $2^0\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^5\cdot 7^7$.

Comment: @plop: Thanks. However, I didn't exactly get how you indexed the rows to get 0, 3, 5, 7. We need to encode all the 1's of the table, right?

Comment: I interpreted the rows as the numbers $0,3,5,7$ written in binary. So, the row $1,0,1$ is $1\cdot 2^2+0\cdot 2^1+1\cdot 2^0=5$.

Comment: I don't know how complex your terms are or how many literals are in your terms, but  truth tables  are an easy way to check equivalence and also work for expressions where complex e.g. the De Morgan laws where used to  rewrite them.